# How to automatically force fsck disks after crash in `systemd`?

Tags: systemd, fsck

How to set `systemd` for automatically force `fsck` disks after crash (hard poweroff)?

When I used `sysvinit` (in Arch Linux) as `/sbin/init` I used the hack: in the `rc.local` I create `/forcefsck` file; in the `rc.local.shutdown` I remove it. At boot-up `rc.sysinit` enable force fsck if `/forcefsck` exists.

How to do same in `systemd`? Maybe it has built-in facilities for automatic `fsck` after crush?

Comment: Similar answer [How to btrfs check a root partition](https://serverfault.com/a/830692/101556).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can force `fsck` at boot time by passing `fsck.mode=force` (`auto` is default and `skip` can be used to skip checking at all) as a [kernel command line parameter](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fsck@.service.html) (as of `systemd` v. [213](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-May/019204.html), there's also a second parameter: `fsck.repair` - to control how `fsck` shall deal with unclean file systems at boot; possible values are: `preen` to fix what can be safely fixed, `yes` to answer yes to all questions and `no` is default).

---

Note that [`systemd-fsck` *does not know any details about specific filesystems, and simply executes file system checkers specific to each filesystem type (*`/sbin/fsck.*`*)*.](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fsck@.service.html)
Now, if your filesystem is `xfs` or `btrfs` it will execute `/sbin/fsck.xfs` or `/sbin/fsck.btrfs` respectively. If that does not seem to work maybe you should check the manual page for `fsck.xfs` or `fsck.btrfs` respectively and examine the contents of the said files in `/sbin`.

Comment: For example with Grub: edit `/etc/default/grub`, then append `fsck.mode=force` to the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Then run `update-grub` and `reboot`.

Comment: doesn't work for xfs btw. but hey. this is the future.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to check BTRFS system is to use its own tool `btrfs check`, you must have the root volume unmounted therefore the only option is to really boot from a livecd.

Any advice that ultimately leads to calling `fsck.btrfs` is wrong, this is just a stub that prints out a message and does nothing. This includes answers with `fsck.mode` kernel command line options or `.forcefsck` files as well.

```
[root@nuc ~]# cat /usr/sbin/fsck.btrfs
#!/usr/bin/sh -f
AUTO=false
while getopts ":aApy" c
do
    case $c in
    a|A|p|y)    AUTO=true;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
eval DEV=\${$#}
if [ ! -e $DEV ]; then
    echo "$0: $DEV does not exist"
    exit 8
fi
if ! $AUTO; then
    echo "If you wish to check the consistency of a BTRFS filesystem or"
    echo "repair a damaged filesystem, see btrfs(8) subcommand 'check'."
fi
exit 0
```

However if you are just unsure if everything is okay after poweroutage or something like that, `btrfs check` can perform a readonly check on a mounted filesystem:

```
[root@nuc ~]# btrfs check --readonly --force /dev/sda5
Opening filesystem to check...
WARNING: filesystem mounted, continuing because of --force
Checking filesystem on /dev/sda5
UUID: 8c44de9c-c91b-4ac4-857b-da191dc62274
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space cache
[4/7] checking fs roots
[5/7] checking only csums items (without verifying data)
[6/7] checking root refs
[7/7] checking quota groups skipped (not enabled on this FS)
found 3628683264 bytes used, no error found
total csum bytes: 3093864
total tree bytes: 136937472
total fs tree bytes: 126074880
total extent tree bytes: 6455296
btree space waste bytes: 23047273
file data blocks allocated: 5676253184
 referenced 4705763328
```