# Check `fsck` automatically

Tags: linux, startup, systemd, init, fsck

I need to run `fsck` so that it automatically fixes problems (i.e., `fsck -y`). And because I am using "systemd" instead of "init" in the linux system, I cannot modify the `/etc/default/rcS`.

So what should I do to make this check run automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? Each time you mount the fs? If so, you could consider `tune2fs`. E.g.: `tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sda1` to run fsck each time you mount /dev/sda1 partition. It only works with ext2/ext3 volumes.

Comment: I hqve got this error when i start the machine:
`/etc/sda2: unexpected inconsistency; run fsck manually` 
I waht that the check will be auto, not manually

Comment: If that error pops up there you have a serious error that should be looked at manually.

Comment: [How to automatically force fsck disks after crash in `systemd` ?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50762)

Answer (score 3):

In the structure of the `/etc/fstab` file you can request the filesystem to be checked each time the system is booted - example :

```
/dev/sda1       /       ext4      errors=remount-ro,relatime      0       1
/dev/sda2       swap    swap      defaults        0       0
proc            /proc   proc      defaults        0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs     defaults        0       0
devtmpfs        /dev    devtmpfs  rw              0       0
```

The last column (6th) indicates in which order you want the filesystems be checked at boot time. 0 means no check, 1 the first check, 2 the second, ... Filesystem with the same *pass* number are checked in parallel.

**For information and completness:**

- First column : device of the filesystem
- Second column : where to mount the filesystem
- Third column : type of filesystem
- Fourth column : options passed to `mount` when mounting the filesystem
- Fifth column : if the filesystem needs to be included (1) or not (0) by the `dump`
  command
- Sixth column : pass of the automatic filesystem check at boot, 0 means no check.

If the filesystem check returns a fatal error during boot, you will be prompted to enter into the filesystem repair mode (basically single-user mode text console).

Comment: FYI: Op left a comment after you answered clarifying that he/she wants to run `fsck -y`; `fsck` is already being run (just without `-y`).