# Meaning of the last two colum values in /etc/fstab

Tags: rhel, fstab

I just wanted to know the values of last two column in /etc/fstab redhat linux. I used to give as  1 2 or 0 0 sometime but not sure the real meaning of it. Can anyone explain please.

Comment: `man fstab` can explain it. If you don't understand something, cite it in your question and ask what you didn't understand.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/9939/158442

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122553/117549

Answer (score 1):

Copy out of `man fstab`

```
The fifth field (fs_freq).
          This field is used by dump(8) to determine which filesystems need to be  dumped.   Defaults  to  zero
          (don't dump) if not present.

The sixth field (fs_passno).
          This  field  is  used  by  fsck(8) to determine the order in which filesystem checks are done at boot
          time.  The root filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1.  Other filesystems should  have
          a  fs_passno  of 2.  Filesystems within a drive will be checked sequentially, but filesystems on dif‐
          ferent drives will be checked at the same time to utilize  parallelism  available  in  the  hardware.
          Defaults to zero (don't fsck) if not present.
```