# Force fsck at boot time on the root file system (prior to mounting file systems, without Single-User mode)

Tags: freebsd, fsck

[How to automatically force fsck disks after crash in `systemd`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50762/how-to-automatically-force-fsck-disks-after-crash-in-systemd) - does not mean anything.

Setting `fsck_y_enable="YES"` and `background_fsck="NO"` in `/etc/rc.conf` don't do anything.

My root file system is not clean and has a lot of errors (due to a power outage - unexpected shutdown, not because hard drive or hardware are bad).

`fsck` shows errors:

```
root@host2:/usr/home/alex # fsck
** /dev/mirror/gm0p2 (NO WRITE)
** Last Mounted on /
** Root file system
** Phase 1 - Check Blocks and Sizes
** Phase 2 - Check Pathnames
** Phase 3 - Check Connectivity
** Phase 4 - Check Reference Counts
UNREF FILE I=8268305  OWNER=root MODE=140777
SIZE=0 MTIME=Jun  6 21:58 2014
CLEAR? no
```

[skipped 100+ lines]

I don't have physical or KVM access to the server.
This is `gmirror`ed drive

```
FreeBSD host2.domain.tld 9.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE #0 r255898: Thu Sep 26 22:50:31 UTC 2013 root@bake.isc.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64

# Device                Mountpoint      FStype  Options Dump    Pass#
/dev/mirror/gm0p2       /               ufs     rw      1       1
/dev/mirror/gm0p3       none            swap    sw      0       0
```

Comment: Hm, what is your `fstab`? I heard creating a (presumably blank) `forcefsck` file in `/` (root) might work. Might give it a try.

Comment: `touch /forcefsck` didn't do it.

Comment: Are you using "initramfs" ?

Answer (score 3):

FreeBSD has properly working forced unmount, so you don't really need to do this at boot. Just log in (remotely), remount rootfs as read-only (`mount -fur /`), do fsck manually (`fsck -y /`) and then reboot the machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a command to be run early in the boot process (still in single user mode) add them to the shell script `/etc/rc.early`

something like `fsck -fy /` added to that file will force it to do a scan and answer 'yes' to all prompts.

Do not forget to remove it from `rc.early` when you are done, else it will run on every startup

Comment: Support for /etc/rc.early is now deprecated

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/rc.initial.reboot` uses the `nextboot` command to reboot an run `fsck` 5 times:

```
/sbin/nextboot -e "pfsense.fsck.force=5"
```

You can run this manually or add it to any script to trigger `fsck` the next time it boots.

I tested this in version 2.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

As of FreeBSD 10.3, you can achieve this by temporarily modifying `/etc/rc.d/root` to run `/sbin/fsck -fy /`.

Here is the current script, modified to include that command commented out; uncomment to perform the fsck.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# $FreeBSD: stable/10/etc/rc.d/root 177062 2008-03-11 17:21:14Z delphij $
#

# PROVIDE: root
# REQUIRE: fsck
# KEYWORD: nojail

. /etc/rc.subr

name="root"
start_cmd="root_start"
stop_cmd=":"

root_start()
{
    # root normally must be read/write, but if this is a BOOTP NFS
    # diskless boot it does not have to be.
    #
    case ${root_rw_mount} in
    [Nn][Oo] | '')
        ;;
    *)

       # Uncomment the below line to run fsck on root during boot:
       #/sbin/fsck -fy /

        if ! mount -uw /; then
            echo 'Mounting root filesystem rw failed, startup aborted'
            stop_boot true
        fi
        ;;
    esac

    umount -a >/dev/null 2>&1

    # If we booted a special kernel remove the record
    # so we will boot the default kernel next time.
    if [ -x /sbin/nextboot ]; then
        /sbin/nextboot -D > /dev/null 2>&1
    fi
}

load_rc_config $name
run_rc_command "$1"
```

Comment: That's a little hacky, but working. But it should be `/sbin/fsck -fy /`