# Is my root btrfs being fsck-ed / checked?

Tags: btrfs, fsck

I am running `systemd`, and [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fsck#Forcing_the_check) said to pass the kernel parameter `fsck.repair=yes` to have all filesystems checked.

Trying this, my ESP partition (FAT32) was dutifully checked, but there are no journal lines matching the strings `fsck`, `btrfs`, `check` or the device name which indicate that anything happened on `/` itself.

I believe that btrfs-check is not being run.

How can I find the last `btrfs check` date/timestamp of a filesystem?

Comment: `btrfs`usually does not need to be `fsck`d; some say it is useless (see e.g. http://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2014-03-19_Btrfs-Tips_-Btrfs-Scrub-and-Btrfs-Filesystem-Repair.html). To check `btrfs`you use `scrub`, which should be run online on a regulary basis (through `cron`, eg; see http://superuser.com/questions/904331/how-does-btrfs-scrub-work-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: The `scrub` man page disagrees with you: `Note
           Scrub is not a filesystem checker (fsck) and does not verify nor repair structural damage in the filesystem.`   While a check at boot may not safely be able to *correct* structural issues, having them *detected* is extremely useful. `btrfs-scrub` would tell me if I had [bitrot](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/01/bitrot-and-atomic-cows-inside-next-gen-filesystems/) in my accessible data or metadata, but only `btrfs-check` would tell me (e.g.) if there was an inode without any references.

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question - your btrfs partitions won't be checked because `systemd-fsck`, [as I said here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50772), executes the specific file checker - in this case `/sbin/fsck.btrfs` which is just a script that does nothing and exists with `0` (unless device does not exist) - you can view its contents with `cat /sbin/fsck.btrfs`. See also [the discussion here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=625967)