# Debian 10 - Commands stop working in console after laptop being on for a while

Tags: debian, x11, awesome

A couple times after waking my laptop up from sleep after I use it for around a minute all commands stop working and my firefox tabs give errors. When I type any commands in console they all give a message of "command not found" including commands such as su and sudo leaving me no other option but to force shutdown the laptop with the power button. I am also no longer able to open any other programs, but am still able to navigate to different tags and windows. I am using Debian 10 with awesomewm and lightdm. My laptop is a thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th generation if it matters.

Comment: are you saying that a command, such as `ls`, gives you an error message?

Comment: could be a hardware fault, perhaps faulty RAM or a dying hard disk.    do you see lots of disk errors in `/var/log/kern.log`?

Answer (score 0):

> I type any commands in console they all give a message of "command not found" including commands such as su and sudo

> I am also no longer able to open any other programs, but am still able to navigate to different tags and windows.

Do these symptoms persist after reboot?

If they do, you are likely to have either severe filesystem damage (causing system directories to be unreachable), or worse, **physical disk failure**.

- I have answered [a really similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542554/got-input-output-error-when-execute-any-commands) about this recently (though that case was a server, rather than laptop, and the damage wasn't bad enough for command directories to be unreachable).

  **See [my answer of that question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542554/got-input-output-error-when-execute-any-commands/542574#542574) for a diagnostic procedure**, together with solution for each diagnostic result.

Comment: They go away after reboot but sometimes come back after left on for a while. We are talking being left on for 8+ hours or more it doesn't seem to come consistently. The laptop is less than a week old so I doubt it could be physical disk failure. It also seems to be fixed by disabling wibox in my awesome config, I will report back in to see if it's really fixed.